# Transfer Data between Macs

Tags: macos, data-transfer

I have a local web development environment setup with Brew, Nginx, PHP, MySQL, Ruby, Gem, Sass, and so many other packages out there that it would probably be a nightmare to set it up again with the same exact versions on a new machine. These packages are usually installed outside of the /Users directory.

So my question is, does the built-in OS X transfer Mac feature support transferring these type of files, and configurations that are located outside of the /Users/ folder and in system directories such as /usr/local or /etc, etc..?

Comment: Which "built-in OS X transfer Mac feature" are you referring to?

Comment: If you want to migrate all of your data from one mac to another, you can use Migration Assistant that's found in the applications folder under Utilities.

Comment: You describe the setup process as quite tedious. Do you know or have considered using the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager? I highly recommend it (not affiliated).

Comment: @vutran i need your help just to configure the Nginx on MAC if you are there

Answer (score 1):

If you make and then restore a complete Time Machine backup or use Migration Assistant you should have no problem moving everything to a new machine and having it work as expected. Otherwise I'm afraid you'll have to reinstall all of your tools and libraries.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different spencer! However, requests for clarification should not be in answers. Please, once you have sufficient reputation, comment. It is fairly easy to get 50 rep.